# Auto-Reload FTP Content in Flask Server

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, ftp

I am using flask server to pull data from FTP server and serve it (video).
Camera says "OK" to flask server when it send new video to Remote FTP server. And Flask server pulls new video from FTP.
What I need is when flask run get_video function, also refresh content of html so that user will see the new video.

Please note that Camera and User are different clients that both connect to same Flask Server.

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request, render_template, g, redirect
import ftplib
app = Flask(__name__)

def get_video():
    session = ftplib.FTP("****", "*****", "****")
    session.retrbinary("RETR try.mp4", open("static/sc.mp4", "wb+").write)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
     get_video()
     return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Files</title>
    <h1>VIDEO</h1>
    <video width="320" height="240" id="VideoWindow" controls>
        <source src="static/sc.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    </form>
    <form action="/shoot_request">
    <input type="submit" name="shoot" value="GetNew"/>
    </form>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#VideoWindow').load(window.location.href + '#VideoWindow');
    }, 5000);
    });
    </script>
    '''
@app.after_request    # This did not work
    def add_header(response):
        response.cache_control.max_age = 10
    return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a flag file. Camera and html script requests file's value from server periodically. If it is a spesific value camera starts recording and sends it over FTP then server changes flag's value to another value. If html script gets that value, it reloads itself and server changes flag's value to default.

Also I added random time stamp to the end of video link
for example:

```
"<video src="dynamic/sc.mp4?t=%d" type="video/mp4" controls> </video>" % random_value
```

Because browser did not want to reload video since it's path did not change.

Anyway, if anyone who need something like this, can use this method. Not 100% efficient but it works.

Regards

Suat